# is there a way to list all 'indexes IDs' (keys) on a bash associative array variable?

Tags: bash, array

I have this array:

```
declare -A astr
```

I add elements to it:

```
astr[elemA]=123
astr[elemB]=199
```

But later on I need to know what are the indexes IDs (elemA and elemB) and list them.

```
echo "${astr[@]}" #this only get me the values...
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can get the list of "keys" for the associative array like so:

```
$ echo "${!astr[@]}"
elemB elemA
```

You can iterate over the "keys" like so:

```
for i in "${!astr[@]}"
do   
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${astr[$i]}"
done
```

#### Example

```
$ for i in "${!astr[@]}"; do echo "key  : $i"; echo "value: ${astr[$i]}"; done
key  : elemB
value: 199
key  : elemA
value: 123
```

#### References

- [How to iterate over associative array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-array-in-bash)

Comment: I just found it also works for numerically indexed arrays also: `astr2=(a b c d e);echo ${!astr2[@]};unset astr2[2];echo ${!astr2[@]}` thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower - Yeah if you roll the edits back on my answer you'll see that i had originally included the numeric index too, but then droped it since you wanted named hashes.

Comment: Note that `${!var[index]}` doesn't work, only `${!var[@]}` or `${!var[*]}` do :(

Comment: @i336_ - take the `!` out so it's `${var[index]}`. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: Sorry, clarification: I was trying to determine the associative key for numeric index *n*. I realized I can easily do `keys=(${!var[@]})` and then `${keys[n]}`, giving me the index, but around the same time I also realized I need to rethink my approach.

Comment: and, inside functions, the only way I found (when passing an array id as parameter) was to use `declare -n ref="$1"`, and then use ref to do anything you would with the array normally (least `declare -p ref` will differ of course)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.